# Independent VueJS components with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I made some SPA using vuejs-templates/webpack and that's ok. But now I am developing a website, almost everything is static, so there's no need to be a SPA. I already made the pure html/css layout.

Now I will make some pages with forms and dynamic content, I would like to use vue components **inside** these pages.

Tell me which of this ideas is the best or give me a better option:

1. **Multiple entries in webpack:** I don't know very well how to do it, but I guess I can create a webpack project by scratch and render multiple entries that I include in the pages I want.
2. **Use browserify:** I didn't want to do this, but sounds like a good option... I could use vueify to render *.vue components
3. **Use Nuxt:** I never tried, but seems a good option too, I could make a "SPA" with SSR.

Tell me if you have another idea.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Don't rule out just referencing Vue as a script file. No bundle, no compilation step. You lose single file components, but you can get something very like them by using js template literals. If your needs are simple and you don't want to impact on the rest of the site, this could be a fine solution.

Comment: You are right about that... but I wish to use `.vue` files because I like the way it's designed... If I don't find a solution I will end up doing your way. Thanks for the answer